# how to take amazon instance backup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two instances running. I have done lot of configuration on the instances. I want to shutdown the server so I do not get charged but I don't want to lose my configurations and data stored on instances.

What should I do to make sure I do not lose data ?

Comment: You can turn off ("stopping") an instance without deleting ("terminating") it. You can also save an [AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html). You may find yourself owing money in either situation, depending on how much it costs to store your volumes.

Comment: Did you use only EBS to store your data? If you used instance store (local disk), you must copy the data to EBS (network disk).

Answer (score 1):

So basically create an image as following:

[image: Create Image]

and then if you don't want to lose any state you can use the 'no reboot' option:

[image: No reboot]

Comment: A few caveats with this approach: (1) it won't backup anything stored on any non-root volumes (ephemeral or EBS, doesn't matter); (2) it might result in an inconsistent image, unless you ensure that all filesystem caches are properly flushed before the image creation start.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way i see is click on the instance > actions > create image. Then launch a new instance from that image whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the instance that you launch from a public AMI and then save that configuration as a custom AMI for your own use. Instances that you launch from your AMI use all the customizations that you've made.

For the detail: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html